# How to navigate to a new page/Component ? react chatbot

Tags: reactjs, chatbot

I have been trying to create a react-based chatbot, in that if a user presses an option/button from the chatbot I want to display a component outside of the chatbot and on the same page.

this is my sample chatbot Code :

```
     {
                  id: "summary-end-graph",
                  asMessage: false,
    
                  component: <Calculators/>,
                  
                  trigger: "summary-ends-last",
                  waitAction : true,
                  delay: 1300,
    
                },
```

I have mentioned here as **Calculators** is a different component

Sample code of the Calculators component

```
    class Calculators extends Component {
      constructor(props) {
        super(props);  
        const { steps } = this.props;
        const { salaryanswer, rate } = steps;
    ................
```

When the user clicks on an option inside the chatbot, the calculators component should come out of the chatbot. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can call the component outside the chatbot first and add conditional rendering like this:

```
<ChatBot optionClicked={this.toggleOption} />
{
  optionClicked ?
    <Calculators/> :
    <div></div>
}
```

before that you would set up the optionClicked state in

```
    constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {optionClicked : false};
    }
```

and a function toggleOption

```
toggleOption = () => {
    this.setState({ optionClicked: !optionClicked })
  }
```

Then in the chatbot you would click the button:

```
    <button onClick={() => this.props.optionClicked()}>Option</button>
```

Now clicking the button should toggle the component outside the chatbot.